# LINQ multiple group by and then getting the first group by value count

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I have a linq query like followin:

```
var _transactionsList = TransactionsData
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemID, x.Title, x.GalleryURL })
                .Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults
                {
                    ItemID = pr.Key.ItemID,
                    Title = pr.Key.Title,
                    GalleryURL = pr.Key.GalleryURL,

                    ItemPrice = pr.OrderByDescending(a => a.TransactionDate).First().ItemPrice,

                    TotalSoldItems = pr.Count(),
                    TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
                    AveragePrice = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
                }).ToList();
```

I'm trying to fetch the total sold items value by grouping it by like this:

```
ItemID    Sales    ItemName

1          1         Item1
1          3         Item1
1          5         Item1
1          6         Item1
2          2         Item2
2          2         Item2
2          2         Item2
2          2         Item2
```

The desired output would be:

```
ItemID   Sales   ItemName
1         15       Item1
2         8        Item2
```

The query above that I wrote gives me wrong values for total sales by saying:

```
 TotalSoldItems = pr.Count(),
```

How can I count, or sum all the sales of one Item which has unique ID(this is what I'm grouping by)...

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

You are using GroubBy wrong way. You create new unique object every time. So your `.GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemID, x.Title, x.GalleryURL })` and `.Select(x => new { Key = new { x.ItemID, x.Title, x.GalleryURL}, Value =x })` means the same

If you need unique Id then group by Id only

```
TransactionsData
.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
.Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults
{
    ItemID = pr.Key,
    Title = pr.First().Title,
    GalleryURL = pr.First().GalleryURL,
    ItemPrice = pr.OrderByDescending(a => a.TransactionDate).First().ItemPrice,
    TotalSoldItems = pr.Count(),
    TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
    AveragePrice = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
}).ToList();
```

**Advice**

Optimize your LINQ. You are iterating through collections many times. This is suggested code:

```
TransactionsData
.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
.Select(pr => 
{
    var items = x.pr.ToArray;
    var sum = items.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice);
    return new TransactionsTabResults
    {
        ItemID = pr.Key,
        Title = items[0].Title,
        GalleryURL = items[0].GalleryURL,
        ItemPrice = pr.Aggregate((max, cur)=>max.TransactionDate<cur.TransactionDate?cur:max).ItemPrice,
        TotalSoldItems = items.Length,
        TotalRevenuePerItem = sum,
        AveragePrice = sum/items.Length,
    };
}).ToList();
```